# CryptoJS in Adobe Extendscript (ES3): Decrypting String Does Not Work

Tags: json, cryptojs, extendscript

I'm working on a Photoshop CES extension and attempting to encrypt data using CryptoJS. This all works, except when I convert the encrypted data to a string and then try to decrypt it.

**Here's a link to a JS Fiddle that works:**

https://jsfiddle.net/davevsdave/atwpbmr5/3/

This same code in ExtendScript Toolkit or running in Photoshop does not return the correct finalResult var. Here's the code I'm running in extendscript, identical to what is in the above JSFiddle (except $.println instead of console.log and an extra line showing that decrypting the obj works):

```
//JSON from Panel
jsonStr = '{"date":"1563662582633","email":"email@email.com","password":"1234324","uniqueID1":"12345","uniqueID2":"asfdsa-asdfsa-adsfas-sadfsdf-asfsaf\n"}';

//JSON from Panel
jsonStr = '{"date":"1563662582633","email":"email@email.com","password":"1234324","uniqueID1":"12345","uniqueID2":"asfdsa-asdfsa-adsfas-sadfsdf-asfsaf\n"}';

//Encrypt Data
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(jsonStr, 'secret_passcode');

//Convert OBJ to String so I can save it
var encryptedString  = encrypted.toString();
$.writeln('encryptedString is ' + encryptedString);

//Decrypt string - DOES NOT WORK IN EXTENDSCRIPT
var decryptedValue1= CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptedString, 'secret_passcode');
$.writeln('decryptedValue1 is ' +  decryptedValue1);

//Decrypt OBJ - WORKS IN EXTENDSCRIPT
var decryptedValue2= CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, 'secret_passcode');
$.writeln('decryptedValue2 is ' +  decryptedValue2);

//Final Decrypt output from string
$.writeln('finalOutput from  decryptedValue1 is ' + decryptedValue1.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));

//Final Decrypt output from obj
$.writeln('finalOutput from  decryptedValue2 is ' + decryptedValue2.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
```

I'm guessing the issue is Extendscript using ES3. Any suggestions on how I can convert the encrypted data to a string (so I can store it as JSON) and then still be able to decrypt it? Obviously being able to store data I can't decrypt does me no good.

Thanks!

Comment: Actually for me both `decryptedValue1` and `decryptedValue2` were the same objects, but both failed to decrypt to the original string. But when I tried a different cipher algorithm I got the expected string as a result. Maybe it's something particular to AES decoding..?

Comment: I updated the extendscript code in my question to be a bit more clear. Maybe now you'll see where I'm able to get the obj decrypted, but not the string.

What other cipher algorithm did you use? Any chance you could share an example?

Comment: The updated code works the same as before for me. I used `DES`, `Triple DES`, and `Rabbit` from CryptoJS manual: https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#ciphers